# Sort List(of T) by date property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have used the following code previously, with an `short` property type. It worked well.

```
reportUnits.units.Sort(Function(x, y) x.checkInDate.CompareTo(y.checkInDate))
```

This code, however, as above, trying to sort on a `Date` property, does not do anything.

No errors, but also no sorting?

The list contains custom objects with various properties, one of which is checkInDate.

I want to re-order list of objects (units), by checkInDate.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet , this is the second time your doing this to me :-).. and again, when actually taking the time to do a standalone replication of the my issue, as you requested, I find my issue. My property I sort by, and my property I used to "check" the sort, were different date properties of the object. I sorted by one, checked by another. Thanks of the insight, once again.

Comment: @Louis You should be able to close or delete your question if you don't need it any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
reportUnits.units.OrderBy(x => x.checkInDate).ToList();
```

Comment: This will return a new List without changing in existing. I think you should complete a little your answer.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reportUnits.units.OrderBy(Function(x) x.checkInDate)
```

Comment: Thanks, see my comment to the question.